# Can't Save same entry multiple times in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What i'm trying to do is save a room object multiple times in a database but MongoDB shows only 1 entry no matter how many times i insert it. i'm guessing its because the object is same so i was hoping if there is any way around it.

```
 let room = new Room({
  rent,
  roomType,
  NoOfRooms,
  roomMaxOccupancy,
});

for(let i=0;i<NoOfRooms;i++){
  await room.save();
}
```

Comment: *shows only 1 entry*, can you show us how you're querying DB ?

Comment: the answer from "Alonad" below solves it, the _id of the object created in the code above is same. That is why it was showing only 1 room entry,instead of multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is creating a room with a unique _id and then save it multiple times. It is one and the same room. In order to save multiple different rooms you need to have rooms with unique _ids each.

```
for(let i=0;i<NoOfRooms;i++){
  let room = new Room({
    rent,
    roomType,
    NoOfRooms,
    roomMaxOccupancy,
  });
await room.save();
}
```